# Create SFTP user to access specific folder only?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit. I want to create a sftp user to access an existing folder and allow them to download/upload/edit. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well creating ftp server or even sftp is quite simple with vsftpd package but if you really wish to grant some one outside to do ftp login , then you need to take care of some important scenarios. So its better to set up Non-chroot sftp setup so no sftp user can view your system files. This can be done in many methods, well I can explain a simple hack way to achieve your requirement in a simple steps.

Become privileged user.

```
sudo su
```

Install the packages

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd openssh-server
```

Backup the config file and create new one.

```
mv /etc/vsftpd.conf{,.backup}

nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

[download the config file and copy the contents](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23084125/)

save and exit

```
Ctrl + x 
y
```

Restart the vsftp server

```
service vsftpd restart
```

create user for ftp only

```
useradd -g sftpgroup -d /files -s /sbin/nologin sagar
```

Set password for user Sagar

```
sudo passwd sagar
```

Add nologin to shell config to use it.

```
echo "/usr/sbin/nologin" >> /etc/shells
```

Create a group for ftp , so all users under the group can use sftp

```
sudo groupadd sftpgroup
```

Now edit ssh daemon config file to use SFTP /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the line "Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server " and  comment out as follows

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

paste the following at the end of the file

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftpgroup
ChrootDirectory /ftpdir/%u
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Save by Ctrl+x  y

Create directory for ftp files like mkdir -p /ftpdir//files.

```
mkdir -p /ftpdir/sagar/files
```

Give Ownership

```
sudo chown -R sagar:sftpgroup /ftpdir/sagar/files
```

Reboot the system

```
sudo reboot
```

Now use filezilla client to connect  using SFTP or terminal for the same. That's it.

Comment: Do we need a reboot after all? I think just have to restart the FTP service is enough.